# Android Studio - Refactor move files still keeps a copy in original place

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14

In visual Studio when I move files into a package on the same original level, the files that I move also remain where they were.

[image: Picture]

I dragged each of these Kotlin files (AddHappyPlaceActivity and MainActivity) into the "activities" package, then pressed refactor in the screen that appears. I would expect the original files to not appear.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: that doesn't seem/sound right, from what you've described (if i'm understanding it correctly) the files should definitely be moved to `activities` and there shouldn't be duplicates

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you record a screencast? Are there any errors in idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file after reproducing?

Comment: Do you mean the file disappears from an old package after you close/open Project tool window?

Comment: I can confirm I'm also seeing this issue. If I check the OS file system, the file shows as moved correctly, but in Android Studio it still appears in its old location. I'm using Arctic Fox Patch 3 on macOS 11.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting an answer is because I don't have enough reputation.
after refactoring the file actually moves there but it is bug I also have noticed, A copy of the file seems to be present in the old places even after refactoring but after refreshing It is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve this issue by simply closing and re-opening Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug of Android Studio.  When I restart Android Studio, the file only was shown in the new location. The copy was disappeared.